# Fulcalendar in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, libraries

I'm using a fullcalendar library in my lightning component but the calendar is not showing up.
**Component:**

```
    <aura:component >
   <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jQuery}"/> 
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/FullCalendar/lib/jquery.min,
                           /resource/FullCalendar/lib/moment.min,
                           /resource/FullCalendar/fullcalendar"/>
    <div id="calendar">
        <div onclick="{!c.comp}">test</div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
comp : function(component, event, helper) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-02-12',
        editable: true,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: {
            url: 'php/get-events.php',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });

   });
  }
})
```

On click of test I want to show the calendar.
But I'm getting this error **$(...).fullCalendar is not a function TypeError**

Comment: Check if necessary plugins for `fullCalendar` is loaded. Do you really need `document.ready()`?

Comment: if the below answer helped resolve your question, please consider marking it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [ltng:require](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm) component allows multiple libraries to be specified but loads them asynchronously. However, it provides an `afterScriptsLoaded` event which is the best place to hook up your logic as that call will be made once all the libraries have been loaded:

```
<aura:component >
    <div aura:id="calendar"></div>
    <ltng:require scripts="{! ... }" afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.scriptsLoaded }"/>
</aura:component>
```

then in the controller:

```
({
    scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var c = component.find("calendar");
            var el = c.getElement();
            $(el).fullCalendar({...});
        });
    }
})
```

Note the use of `find` rather than the hard-coding of a HTML Id (which would only allow one instance of your component and also potentially clash with other hard coding of the same Id value).

I am unsure about the value of `$(document).ready` in this case but don't think it will do any harm.

Be sure to use the library versions listed in [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

Comment: I use this same setup and it works for me. The component.find() to get the div element is essential. This should be the accepted answer. Just saying ;)